# How to write a program in python that returns yes if the first letter in the string is repeated, and returns no if the first letter doesn’t repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python 3, how do you write a program that can access the first letter/character in a string and return yes if that is repeated throughout the rest of the string

Comment: Strings have indexing, so you can access the first letter with `[0]`

Comment: How would ***you*** write the program? Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just check if it exists

```
def is_first_letter_repeated(mystring):
    return mystring[0] in mystring[1:] if mystring else False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the string, which has indexing

something like:

```py
first_letter = parsed_string[0]
for char in parsed_string[1:]:
    # logic you want to implement 
    # then return true or false based on that logic
```

Comment: I'm not pleased with calling a python string an "indexed array of characters", as unlike a python array, strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def first_letter_repeats(string):
    # returns true or false as output
    return string[0] in string[1:]

def as_yes_no(string):
    # same function with yes or no as output
    bool_ = string[0] in string[1:]
    # True / False equals 0 / 1
    return ['no', 'yes'][bool_]

# Results:
first_letter_repeats('aaron')  # True
as_yes_no('aaron')  # 'yes'
first_letter_repeats('arona')  # True
as_yes_no('arona')  # 'yes'
first_letter_repeats('aron')  # False
as_yes_no('aron')  # 'no'
```

The shortest Version would be defining a lambda function.
Don't use it unless you're sure why you do it.

```py
>>> first_repeats = lambda x: ['no', 'yes'][x[0] in x[1:]]
>>> first_repeats('aaron')
'yes'
>>> first_repeats('arona')
'yes'
>>> first_repeats('aron')
'no'
>>>
```